# Lifetime problem with Iterator implementation

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm getting this lifetime error from the rust compiler.
I would like to know how to change the next method to make it work.

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
   --> src/sequence.rs:154:9
    |
138 | impl<'a, T, S> Iterator for Sequence<'a, T, S>
    |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
144 |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
154 |         self.nth_element(iter_index)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
```

The code:

```rust
impl<'a, T, S> Iterator for Sequence<'a, T, S>
where
    Self: 'a,
{
    type Item = &'a T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let iter_index = self.iter_index;

        if iter_index >= self.len() {
            self.iter_index = 0;
            return None;
        }

        self.iter_index += 1;

        self.nth_element(iter_index)
    }
}
```

[The full source code](https://github.com/crazyrat13/seqgen)

Comment: This may be from `nth_element` being wrong. You should add that function as well as the definition of `Sequence` to the question.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Your code is incomplete (you didn't show how `Sequence ` looks like and what method it implements) so we cannot reproduce and then help you.

Comment: I add a link to the full source code on github

Comment: The code needs to be embedded in the question. Links to external sites are not enough. And the code example should also be **minimal**, meaning it won't include the full code but the shortest snippet necessary to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rust is stopping you from doing something that really is unsafe!

Here is an example of something that could go wrong if Rust allowed this:

```
fn bad(seq: &mut Sequence<'_, String, Defined>) {
    let item = seq.next();  // get a reference to an item
    seq.reset();            // drop all items
    println!("{}", *item);  // DANGER: access a dropped item
}
```

If you want `.next()` to return references with lifetime `'a`, you have to somehow make the values really live as long as `'a`, which seems difficult. It'll be easier to make `.next()` return the values themselves, or clones of them, rather than references.